# SSRS - link to a survey works, but if I change it to another survey I get rsItemsNotFound

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reporting-services, visual-studio-2019

I'm looking at a VS project which stores report records in a database table (here it holds things like the report url, name, etc.). We have a link that when you click it, it opens a report as a PDF. This one works fine.

I duplicated this report, made appropriate changes for a new report, and also copied the exact same format when adding a new row for it in the database (just with its own name and different url, etc.).

When I change the link in the code to grab the new report (nothing in the code has changed aside from which report ID it grabs from the database), it gives me 'folder/reportname' cannot be found (rsitemsnotfound).

Both reports are under the same folder location, and in the code it definitely grabs all the information from the database, and it uses the same data source credentials for the reports. No spelling errors either. Both reports work in the survey designer preview btw.

It seems like there is an issue with connecting to the data source for the new report, but again all the credentials and everything are the same so I am a bit stumped as to why this error is happening.

I am using Visual Studio 2019, I am not sure if it matters but the previous reports likely were made using earlier versions

Comment: have you actually deployed the report to the report server?

Comment: Yes it's been deployed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue, very silly of me to not realize. In the DB I saved the report name in the path as something different than the name of the rdl

Comment: I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can click '✔' to mark your reply as an answer.